# Read shapefile attributes using talend

Tags: geospatial, talend, shapefile

I am using the spatial plug-ins for TOS to perform the following task:
I have a dataset with X and Y coordinates. I have also a shapefile with multi polygons and two metadata attributes, `name` and `Id`. The idea is to look-up the names in the shapefile with the coordinates.  With a point in polygon will be determined which polygon belongs a point to.

I am using the shapefile input component which points to the  .shp file.

I am facing to hurdles:

- I cannot retrieve the *name* and *Id* from the file.  I can only see an attribute call *the_geom*. How can I read the metadata?
- The second thing is, the file contains a multi polygon and I don't know how to iterate over it in order to perform a *Contains* or *intersect* with the points.

Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Attributes are actually not stored in the .shp, in the .dbf file that comes with a shapefile. You should be able to inspect that file with e.g. LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc, rows in the .dbf should be in the same order as the shapes in the .shp.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your input @chrki

I managed to solve my tasks in this way:

1) Create a generic schema under metadata:

[image]

As the .dbf file was in the same directory of the shapefile Talend automatically recognized the metadata:

[image]

2) This is the job overview:

[image]

3) I read the shape file using a sShapeFileInput component:

[image]

4) The shapefile contains multipolygons and I want to have polygons. My solution was to use a sSimplify component. I used the default settings.

5) The projection of the shapefile was "MGI / Austria Lambert" which corresponds to EPSG 31287. I want to re-project it as EPSG 4326 (GCS_WGS_1984) which is the one used by my input coordinates.

[image]

6)  I read the x, y coordinates from a csv file.

7) With a s2DPointReplacer I converted the x,y coordinates as Point(x,y) (WKT)

[image]

8) Finally I created an expression in a tMap to get only the polygons and points with an intersection. I guess a "contains" would also work:

[image]

I hope this helps someone else.

Kind regards,

Paul